# Two holes have I!

Tags: riddle

> I can sound like someone with the answer,
>
> If you figure me out, your answer could be on me,
>
> Why not dive in and give it a blow?

What am I?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are

> a nose !

*I can sound like someone with the answer*

> *Nose* sounds like *knows*.

*If you figure me out, your answer could be on me*

> To hit something on the nose is to be right/accurate, which is what this answer is.

*Why not dive in and give it a blow?*

> I'm *nose diving* into solving this riddle; you blow your nose when you have a cold.

And about the title:

> A nose has two nostrils.

Comment: Yep.  Figured this'd be a quick one. +1